# Incorrect date axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
> dt
        Month Var
1  2020-01-31 237
2  2020-02-29 205
3  2020-03-31 352
4  2020-04-30 213
5  2020-05-31 455
6  2020-06-30 284
7  2020-07-31 268
8  2020-08-31 273
9  2020-09-30 378
10 2020-10-31 289
11 2020-11-30 346
12 2020-12-31 432
```

and I plot it using:

```
dt %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Var, group = 1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")
```

and this gives:

[image]

I don't understand why the axis labels don't align properly. For instance, the first bar should be Jan (not Feb) and the last one should be Dec (not Jan)

Data is available here:

```
dt <- structure(list(Month = structure(c(18292, 18321, 18352, 18382, 
                                   18413, 18443, 18474, 18505, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18627), class = "Date"), 
               Var = c(237, 205, 352, 213, 455, 284, 268, 273, 378, 289, 
                       346, 432)), row.names = 1:12, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why not use `geom_line`? `geom_bar`/`geom_col` is more for categorical data, i.e. visualising a quantity `y` as a function of different category levels `x`. Using `geom_bar`/`geom_col` with `Date`/timeseries data is unusual.

Comment: @MauritsEvers But the main problem would remain, the first month would still be Feb. I believe that it has to do with the end of month days.

Comment: @MauritsEvers the business owner wants a bar chart

Comment: @RuiBarradas Are you sure? If I replace `geom_bar` with `geom_line` and do `scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks = "1 month")` the first point shows up where it should: to the left of "Feb" (i.e. in January). Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the issue.

Comment: @MauritsEvers No in my plot with that `scale_x_date`, it shows above Feb.

Comment: @RuiBarradas That's very odd! By "above Feb" I guess you mean to the right of the "Feb" label/grid line? That's not the case for me. The line starts to the left of the vertical grid line indicating the start of "Feb". Are you sure you're doing `dt %>% ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Var, group = 1)) + geom_line() + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks = "1 month")`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers My line starts *on* the vertical grid line indicating the start of "Feb". That's why I'm saying that the problem remains. The answer below solves it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Strange and can't reproduce. `floor_date` means ignoring any day information from the date, effectively turning the `Date` into an ordered factor of month names. If that's what OP wants it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

By default the month labels are shown of the month which are the closest. Use `floor_date` to make the dates first date of the month.

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = lubridate::floor_date(Month, 'month'), y = Var, group = 1)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  xlab('Month')
```

[image]